# Limitations of particle in cell method for high density plasma

Tags: simulation, modeling

Are there any limitations of particle in cell (PIC) method for high density plasma? To be more specific, is modeling of a narrow channel of high density plasma possible or are there any limitations connected with PIC approximation?